# AnyLogic - adding agents in the network

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to AnyLogic and I have a problem that I'm not able to solve...

I "Main", section "Space and network" I put "Layout type" and "Network type" as "Random" and I checked the box "Apply on startup"...at the beginning I have my nice social network

[image]

Yet agents born and die...the problem is that when I add agents `main.add_individuals()` the newly created agents do not have connections! So I when all the intial agents are dead I find my self with agents but with no network!

[image]

How can I do? When I add a new agent I want it to connects with others :S

Thanks!!!

---

I tried the following
[image]
but it didn't work...I always end up with a population without network

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to do it manually during agent creation (the "On startup" parameter) with the connections.connectTo(Agent). This code will connect the agent to about half of the agent in your agent list. You could also use normal() instead of 0.5 to get a more realistic number of connections.

```
for(Agent ag : yourListOfAgents){
     if(random() < 0.5){
         connections.connectTo(ag);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Nikolaj , yet I did not manage to make it works :( I edited the question with what I did..

Comment: you should do it in the on startup parameter of your agent, not the main